# Are there any npm modules that use async_hooks to retrieve async stack trace?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, stack-trace, node8.2, async-hooks

There is a new API in node 8 called 'async_hook' which I believe should make it possible for a module author to print async stack traces.  I'm looking for something similar to chrome dev-tools async stack-trace implementation but for use from console during dev/debug.

I know this will come with performance overhead -- but that's fine with me.

Is anyone aware of any modules under development that do this?

Answer (score -1):

I wrote an npm module to track a user request context. 
You can use it or take some ideas from it.

[The NPM module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-request-context) and [a blog post about it](https://medium.com/@guysegev/async-hooks-a-whole-new-world-of-opportunities-a1a6daf1990a)